# Disable all links on the site if domain is X

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, hyperlink

So I have this problem of having 2 websites in Drupal (1 test and 1 public), on 2 different domains. Both of them have some static links, the problem is that the public version has now a lot of links that target the test version.

I tried to modify the domain in .htaccess with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !new-example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But this brakes a lot of things in js files. I know it's a mess, but it's ok for me if I just put a command to disable all the static links that users can see in the front end.

Is there any way to achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: What is the old/new, the test/production host name?

Comment: The specific rule you posted most likely breaks a lot of things because it is invalid syntax. A look into your http server's error log file you tell you so. You forgot the closing `]`...

Comment: @arkascha sorry, the mistake has happened when I put the code here, I edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use absolute paths for links - use root relative paths instead.

So don't use:

```
http://test.dev/contact
```

i.e.

```
<a href = "http://test.dev/contact">Contact</a>
```

but just use

```
/contact
```

i.e.

```
<a href = "/contact">Contact</a>
```

Use some search/replace trough the template files / database dump to fix all existing links.